# Проблемы с использованием pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv, python-3.5, pyautogui

Пытаюсь использовать функцию `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` и подобные ей `pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen` и `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen`.

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
s = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('test6.png')
pyautogui.moveTo(s)
```

После исполнения этого кода Python ничего не делает, не двигает, не кликает и не выписывает ошибку. Изображение 'test6.png' это изображение иконки меню действий на StackOverflow ([image: Иконка меню]). Изображение обрезал максимально, но так, чтобы было понятно, что это меню. С разными вариантами функции `pyautogui.locateOnScreen` тоже возникают разные ошибки:

```
pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen – TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'generator'
```

Видимо тип данных, которые присылаются в эту функцию не соответствует тем, которые нужны. Но в документации всё работало

```
pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen
```

– просто молчит, и ничего не происходит. Когда я пытаюсь кликнуть по тому изображению с помощью функции pyautogui.click, которое оно как бы нашло, то ничего не происходит: ни клика, ни ошибки.

Когда я пишу:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
sleep(5)
s = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('test6.png')
print(s)
```

Python пишет None, но в примерах из документации Pyautogui все эти функции работали и Python писал либо координаты 'x, y' либо кортеж из значений высоты, ширины, отступа слева и сверху.

OpenCV для Python у меня установлен, функция pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen его не видит и всё равно использует pyscreeze. Нужно ли импортировать OpenCV или он должен использоваться сам? Никакие окна у меня не закрывают иконку, и браузер я мышкой не двигаю. В чем проблема никак понять не могу.

Версии: python 3.5.2, pyscreeze 0.1.26, OpenCV 4.2, pyautogui 0.3.1

Работаю с ноутбука Mac OS

Comment: Иконку не видно

Comment: Иконку видно, я проверял на разных вариантах рисунка

Comment: Покажите рисунок иконки который пытаетесь найти

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос как изображение